# Error in Response body in the redirection URL in Jmeter

Tags: testing, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I am trying to do a performance testing for a project where the main URL performs a redirection and the redirection URL returns the token needed to proceed further.

I recorded the script with Jmeter and i can see that the main URL does the redirection with status code as "302" as expected and has the "Location" header in the response body.

But when the redirection URL is hit after the main URL as the sub sample, it returns "307 temporary redirection" in response header and an error message in the response body as "**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing location header in redirect for GET** "

I checked the same scenario in Neoload and i could notice that request sent in Neoload for rediection URL is same as the one sent in JMeter, the response header also matches. But Neoload was able to display the response body with the expected token. In Jmeter, it returned the error message.

Can someone clarify why the response body is not displayed in Jmeter if the same request can work in Neoload. I made sure there is no difference in the request header/body sent for the main URL.

I am pretty sure the issue is related to Jmeter but not sure how to get the proper response body.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is more than one redirect and JMeter doesn't follow it.

You can play with `Redirect automatically` and/or `Follow redirects` boxes in HTTP Request sampler

[image]

also you can use a third-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect which requests are actually being sent, pay attention to literally everything: URL, headers, body, etc.

It should also be possible to disable handling redirects in JMeter completely and extracting the redirect target from the Location header using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) and manually add the next request giving the extracted URL in the "Path" field of the HTTP Request sampler

Comment: I compared my request in Jmeter with fiddler and browser, there is nothing that is different. If I select "Redirect Automatically" it does not return the token as expected and redirection does not happen. My query is that I am getting the proper response header in Jmeter but the response body is not as expected.. Will there be any issues with parsing the response body in Jmeter